# Problems connecting to wireless and the Internet after upgrading to Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, windows-8.1-upgrade

I've used Windows 8.1 since it was released and didn't have any problems for a long time. Then some time ago I began having problems connecting to the Internet and my home modem's wireless network.  For example, web pages loaded incredibly slow (if at all) and when I tried connecting to my wireless network, it said it was taking longer than usual before reporting I had a limited connection. Sometime this would be enough to use the Internet, other times not.  I seem to be able to connect to other wireless networks without any problems.

I've done research online that led me to believe that this problem was caused by a malware, not Windows 8.1. So I used Windows 8's [Refresh Your PC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc) (not *Reset* which would have deleted all of my files), after which my PC went back to Windows version 8, not 8.1. Afterward my Internet worked like it should.

A week or so later, it made me upgrade to Windows 8.1 (I don't remember if I had the choice of keeping Windows 8, but I did the upgrade). After the upgrade I immediately started having the exact same problems again. So I Refreshed my PC again and the problem seemed to have gone away until now, when I had to upgrade to Windows 8.1 a third time (this time I think I was forced, because I didn't even understand how it happened).

Is this normal? Is it likely that the Windows 8.1 upgrade is the root of my Internet problems? If so, is there a way to fix this or a way to keep Windows 8 and ignore the upgrade?

If this is not likely what causes my problems, what could it be? The malware should be gone, since I Refreshed my PC. I have to believe, that the infected file is a torrent file that I still keep in one of my folders, but I reason the malware could install itself only when I actually download the files in the torrent, which I didn't do this time, so I'm pretty confident the malware has nothing to do with it. Plus everything was going perfectly fine up until the Windows 8.1 update.

Thanks for reading through this long description of what has been become an incredibly huge and bothersome problem, and I really hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Quite bigger post. But indeed peculiar case. As you experience issue w.r.t your home modem alone, did you try restarting the modem and check if issue resolves?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, but since it seems to only happen when Windows 8.1 is installed, I doubt my modem has any responsibility in this, for how strange I'm aware it sounds. I think I'm gonna try and reset my pc for the third time, but only if there's a way to dodge the Windows 8.1 upgrade. There is a way to do so, right?

Comment: Are you sure when you reset the computer it went to 8.0 and not 8.1 because 8.1 isn't required and not distribute by Windows Ipdate

Comment: Yes, 100% sure. So, should I just decline everytime it asks me to upgrade to 8.1 or is there a better way or maybe there isn't a way at all?

Comment: Is your Windows Update up to date?

Comment: This I have no idea. Howewer, since it seems to be likely that the problems are in some ways related to Windows 8.1, I'm probably resetting my pc once again, but I don't want Windows 8.1 to be automatically installed again. I found an option regarding updates, and I noticed I had it set to "automatically install all updates". Does that mean that if I set it to "download all updates but ask before installing them" it's not gonna autoinstall Windows 8.1 and that I get to keep Windows 8 forever?